# Restoring files with CrashPlan has errors, what does it mean?

Tags: restore, crashplan

I'm restoring some files with CrashPlan -- well, lots of files, actually -- and it registered some errors. Do you know what they are exactly? Files that couldn't be restored and are lost forever or just a retry?

This is what I see as the error count:

[image]

but the history only shows this:

[image]

**Update: I had to remove the restored directory and re-start, I'm getting errors again.**

Comment: I see this is almost five years old, so it's moot by now, but the screen shot includes "see history", so the history may have more information about what went wrong.